# Can't conditionally render view marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I can't figure out how to use a function to decide which child view to render in marionette. It seems like it should be pretty simple based on the documentation here: https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childview

I found that page from the composite view docs which inferred that using a function to define a childView should be the same for collection and composite views https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-childview)

However, with the following code I am getting the error message "Uncaught TypeError: view.on is not a function." My code is below:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var ToDoModel = require('./models/todo');

var ToDo = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: require('./templates/todoitem.hbs')
});


var TodoList = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  el: '#app-hook',
  template: require('./templates/todolist.html'),

  childView: function(item) {
    return ToDo;
  },
  childViewContainer: 'ul',

  ui: {
    assignee: '#id_assignee',
    form: 'form',
    text: '#id_text'
  },

  triggers: {
    'submit @ui.form': 'add:todo:item'
  },

  collectionEvents: {
    add: 'itemAdded'
  },

  modelEvents: {
    invalid: 'itemInvalid'
  },

  onAddTodoItem: function() {
    this.model.set({
      assignee: this.ui.assignee.val(),
      text: this.ui.text.val()
    });

    if (this.model.isValid()) {
      var items = this.model.pick('assignee', 'text');
      this.collection.add(items);
    }
  },

  itemAdded: function() {
    this.model.set({
      assignee: '',
      text: ''
    });

    this.ui.assignee.val('');
    this.ui.text.val('');
  },

  itemInvalid: function() {
    console.log('this item is invalid!')
  }

});


var todo = new TodoList({
  collection: new Backbone.Collection([
    {assignee: 'Scott', text: 'Write a book about Marionette'},
    {assignee: 'Andrew', text: 'Do some coding'}
  ]),
  model: new ToDoModel()
});

todo.render();
```

Why isn't the ToDo view being rendered?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] using a runnable stack snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as if you are using an older version of Marionette (`LayoutView` for example was removed in version 3) and referencing the documentation for the newest version (currently 3.5.1).

In older versions of Marionette, `childView` as a function is not supported, instead you should use [getChildView](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-getchildview)

So, the relevant portion of your code should look like:

```
var TodoList = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  ...
  getChildView: function(item) {
    return ToDo;
  },
  ...
});
```